# building a social network features using Zend and doctrine

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, design-patterns

I want to add social network features over a content website 
the website is developed in Zend framework and Doctrine 1.2 

social network features like :

 member can **follow** an article ("same as twitter **Follow** concept")

 member can **Follow** another member ("same as twitter **Follow** concept")

 member can **Like** an article ("same as facebook **Like** concept")

What is the best way / design  to make   those Actions ? is it View helper Actions ?

is it AjaxController ?
** i want those actions in ajax 
or make a Follow class in a common library then to make an object in the controller action's function ?

my Project structure is :

-application 
    -- controller
    -- model
    -- view
    -- plugins

-library
  -- commonfunctions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the WebServices pattern so it will make it easy to make calls from client side and server side both. Go through Using AjaxContext with Zend_Rest_Controller and Zend_Rest_Route. Write your custom library first so it will make it easy for you to use your generic component. Ajax controller will save up your like by having postid and userid. Write models for them to interact with database. Active Record approach of Doctrine is good.

Comment: the custom library is a class like **Follow** ?

Comment: Library would be namespace handling all your re-usable class components.